# Как в методе paintComponent узнать расположения окна

Tags: java, окно

Есть класс окна, есть класс панели. Данная панель вложена в окно и на ней что-то рисуется. Как в методе paintComponent этой панели узнать расположение окна на котором эта панель расположена. Что бы можно было реализовать задачу: если окно расположено в одной части экрана - рисовать что-то одно, если в другой - что-то другое.

Comment: Передавайте в объект панель - объект окно при инициализации панели.

Comment: ezhov_da  спасибо. А можно с примером кода? Я понимаю что передаётся здесь "new myPanel()", а принимается здесь "public myPanel() ", но я не уловил что именно вы предлагаете передать

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!